# Need suggestions for out-of-box Netty Framework compatible with sockjs

Tags: netty, sockjs

Are there any classes in Netty Framework that are out-of-box compatible with Sock.js?

We tried writing a simple Websocket Server in Netty using Netty’s official Example, and it is working just fine with HTML 5 compatible Websocket provided by Chrome.

We have modified the Server to vend JSON in required format over /info as required by Sock.js

However, when we try to connect to this Server, we’re seeing following error -

```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://some-server:8092/676/j_5cm5ak/xhr.
    No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource.
    Origin ‘http://some-server’ is therefore not allowed access.
    The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

We’re not using any XHR functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for sock.js in netty itself but [vertx](http://vertx.io) has support for it. See also [SockJSHandler](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/sockjs/SockJSHandler.html)